# How can I use the usb dac driver in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04

The usb dac model is musiland md11 and ubuntu 20.04.
This driver provides Windows-only drivers and does not provide drivers for Linux. The driver must be installed in the window before it can work.
Is there a way to install it from Ubuntu?

Comment: I do have a Fiio Olympus E10K USB DAC. I did not even know about any drivers for it, but it was not necessary. Ubuntu already had some preinstalled driver that recognizes and handles it flawlessly, as far as I can tell. It gets recognized as `DigiHug USB Audio`, with _Digital (S/PDIF)_ and _Analog_ output choices. This was the case on 16.04 and on 20.04 too. Again, never had to install anything, it's practically plug-and-play. I don't know whether it's relevant or not in this specific case, but I had the "Install third party (proprietary) drivers" option enabled when installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least be able to use the DAC out-of-the-box with Linux, that is, select it as your playback audio device.
Without driver, anyway, you won't be able to configure some aspects of it, control its volume, etc. etc.

But you definitely will be able to use it as your audio output device without the need of any driver. I own an Eversolo Z8 DAC, and use it under Linux Mint, and also on a Raspberry Pi 4 running moOde audio; in both places without drivers.