# Ubuntu Speaker Troubleshoot

Tags: sound, hardware

speakers not picked up on latest UBUNTU install, please help I am giving Linux another try I am on hour 22 of trying to get a fully successful install that can be used daily. This is the smoothest system I have managed to get so far.

```
ian@ian-Yoga-7-14ITL5:~$ lspci
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 01)
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 01)
0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a03 (rev 01)
0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 01)
0000:00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 01)
0000:00:07.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev 01)
0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt USB Controller (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt NHI #0 (rev 01)
0000:00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt NHI #1 (rev 01)
0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
0000:00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 20)
0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20)
0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 20)
0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
0000:00:1d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
0000:00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 20)
0000:00:1e.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #1 (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
10000:e0:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 20)
10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
```

```
ian@ian-Yoga-7-14ITL5:~$ lspci -v
0000:00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lenovo 11th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 0
 Capabilities: <access denied>

0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
 Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 210, IOMMU group 1
 Memory at 605e000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
 Memory at 4000000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
 I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]
 Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915

0000:00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a03 (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3805
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 2
 Memory at 605f280000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal
 Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device

0000:00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 126, IOMMU group 3
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=2a, sec-latency=0
 I/O behind bridge: 00004000-00004fff [size=4K]
 Memory behind bridge: 7c000000-881fffff [size=194M]
 Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006000000000-000000601bffffff [size=448M]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport

0000:00:07.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127, IOMMU group 4
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=2b, subordinate=54, sec-latency=0
 I/O behind bridge: 00005000-00005fff [size=4K]
 Memory behind bridge: 6e000000-7a1fffff [size=194M]
 Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006020000000-000000603bffffff [size=448M]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport

0000:00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128, IOMMU group 5
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=55, subordinate=7e, sec-latency=0
 I/O behind bridge: 00006000-00006fff [size=4K]
 Memory behind bridge: 60000000-6c1fffff [size=194M]
 Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006040000000-000000605bffffff [size=448M]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport

0000:00:07.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 129, IOMMU group 6
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=7f, subordinate=a8, sec-latency=0
 I/O behind bridge: 00007000-00007fff [size=4K]
 Memory behind bridge: 52000000-5e1fffff [size=194M]
 Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 0000006060000000-000000607bffffff [size=448M]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport

0000:00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device 380e
 Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 7
 Memory at 605f2c0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>

0000:00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt USB Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 150, IOMMU group 8
 Memory at 605f2b0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
 Kernel modules: xhci_pci

0000:00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt NHI #0 (rev 01) (prog-if 40 [USB4 Host Interface])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 8
 Memory at 605f240000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
 Memory at 605f2dc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
 Kernel modules: thunderbolt

0000:00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt NHI #1 (rev 01) (prog-if 40 [USB4 Host Interface])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 8
 Memory at 605f200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
 Memory at 605f2db000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: thunderbolt
 Kernel modules: thunderbolt

0000:00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 9
 Memory at 605c000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
 Memory at 50000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32M]
 Memory at 605f100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: vmd
 Kernel modules: vmd

0000:00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 20) (prog-if 00 [8250])
 Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP Integrated Sensor Hub
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 10
 Memory at 605f2a0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: intel_ish_ipc
 Kernel modules: intel_ish_ipc

0000:00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 20) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
 Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 167, IOMMU group 11
 Memory at 7a200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
 Kernel modules: xhci_pci

0000:00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 11
 Memory at 605f2d0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Memory at 605f2da000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>

0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 12
 Memory at 605f2cc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
 Kernel modules: iwlwifi

0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27, IOMMU group 13
 Memory at 4017000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
 Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

0000:00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40, IOMMU group 13
 Memory at 4017001000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
 Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

0000:00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 195, IOMMU group 14
 Memory at 605f2d7000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: mei_me
 Kernel modules: mei_me

0000:00:1d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 09ab
 Flags: fast devsel, IOMMU group 15

0000:00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller #0 (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO UART Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 16
 Memory at 4017002000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
 Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

0000:00:1e.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO SPI Controller #1 (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO SPI Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37, IOMMU group 16
 Memory at 4017003000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [virtual] [size=4K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
 Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci

0000:00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 17

0000:00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 211, IOMMU group 17
 Memory at 605f2c8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Memory at 605f000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
 Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci

0000:00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller
 Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 16, IOMMU group 17
 Memory at 605f2d4000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
 I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
 Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
 Kernel modules: i2c_i801

0000:00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IOMMU group 17
 Memory at 4f400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]

10000:e0:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 20) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 149, IOMMU group 9
 Bus: primary=00, secondary=e1, subordinate=e1, sec-latency=0
 I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
 Memory behind bridge: 50000000-500fffff [size=1M]
 Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: pcieport

10000:e1:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809 (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
 Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a801
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ -2147483648, NUMA node 0, IOMMU group 9
 Memory at 50000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: nvme
 Kernel modules: nvme
```

Comment: Please be specific with what you mean by latest Ubuntu. Do you mean the latest *stable* release (Ubuntu 20.10 or the 2020-October release), the latest LTS or 20.04 LTS or the 2020-April release) and I gather you mean a Desktop release. It's best if you're specific.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have your audio device (an `Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)`) work, you have a couple of options:

1. Upgrade your Linux kernel to 5.10.1 (or newer)
2. Update [the `sof-firmware` package](https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin) that is required by the audio driver
3. Wait for Ubuntu 21.04 (which is expected to ship with kernel 5.11, which supports your audio device) or [try the daily release](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) (if you really cannot wait)

Each one of these options has a different amount of risk, so choose the option that you are most comfortable with.

Comment: Or, or, OP can buy a USB-DAC, which is like an "external sound card", attached via USB interface, and might work out-of-the-box, in case the driver(s) that Ubuntu ships with pick up the specific one purchased. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1319132/how-can-i-use-the-usb-dac-driver-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a Lenovo 13s Gen 2 ITL.

This problem seems to plague a lot of new Tiger Lake Laptop.
I tried with 3 different Linux distribution and even with a 21.04, no dice.

The problem seems to be a "pin" amplifier problem.

This seems to be the solution here: [Potential solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263178/20-04-no-speaker-audio-on-hp-spectre-x360-2020-15t-eb000) but I was not able to do it.

From my understanding the culprit is here when you use the aplay command:

```
    aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Seems "Subdevices: 1/1" should be "Subdevices: 0/1".