# Upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 killed audio input and output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.04

So I upgraded my system from 20.04 to 22.04 using the official upgrade window but now my audio is all screwed up. My audio has been replaced with "Dummy Output" and it won't detect input at all. I can lower or increase the volume of this dummy output but there is no output from either my speakers or my earbuds. What can I do so I can hear and say things?

While searching around on AskUbuntu and trying solutions, I did find something sus:

```
guninvalid@guninvalid:~$ pulseaudio -k
guninvalid@guninvalid:~$ echo $?
0
guninvalid@guninvalid:~$ pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
guninvalid@guninvalid:~$ sudo pulseaudio -k
[sudo] password for guninvalid: 
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process
```

Seems pulseaudio won't kill itself for some reason. Is this related?

In accordance with @Terrance's comment:

```
guninvalid@guninvalid:~$ sudo lshw -C multimedia
  *-usb:1                   
       description: Video
       product: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate
       vendor: CN03GGY48LG0016GB63BA01
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@3:6
       logical name: input16
       logical name: /dev/input/event6
       logical name: input17
       logical name: /dev/input/event8
       version: 5.29
       capabilities: usb-2.01 usb
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl latency=64
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:60552d8000-60552dbfff memory:6055000000-60550fffff
```

Comment: I am very sure that I would've been able to help you If I would've upgraded yet. Ran the upgrade to 22.04, went great, after it upgraded, I turned off my system and went. When I came back I get an error when logging in.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1427573/edit) your question and add the output of `sudo lshw -C multimedia`.  Thanks!

Comment: Definitely hard to say, but from this thread with the same audio https://community.frame.work/t/ubuntu-21-10-tiger-lake-sound/11908/25 it appears as a bad board, but I would try other things first.  You might want to also see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321950/ubuntu-speaker-troubleshoot and might need to update the sof-audio.  You might also need to update your GRUB like in:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243369/sound-card-not-detected-ubuntu-20-04-sof-audio-pci